# Roblox studio, the GUI isn't openning

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried with Chatgpt, but the code isn't working. It's to one part workspace. I need when a player touch in the part to appear a GUI.

`script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function() script.Parent.ScreenGui.Frame.Visible = true     end)`

Comment: Where is this script located? It seems to be in workspace because you use touched but then its parent seems to be StarterGui.